# Make a pandas dataframe group by count have a column name

Tags: python, pandas

In python 3.6 and pandas 0.19.0 there is a dataframe "df"

```
id
abc
abc
def
```

I am trying to create a dataframe with a id_count column, which is the same as SQL:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(1) AS id_count FROM table group by id
```

ideal returns:

```
id  id_count
abc 2
def 1
```

I have tried:

```
print (df.groupby(['id'])['id'].count())
```

returns

```
id
abc 2
def 1

print (df.groupby(['id'])['id'].transform('count'))
```

returns

```
0    2
1    1
```

Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this dictionary-based format in the aggregate function with `groupby`.

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['id'].agg({'id_count':'count'})

    id  id_count
0  abc         2
1  def         1
```